# Multi Table Update/Delete in AtK4

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

How can one achieve multi table update/delete in atk4?

Answer (score 1):

You can add related entities on the model level:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466839/204819

If this is not an option, you can always create custom handlers for your "edit" and "delete" button and perform actions using internal ORM or even on Model level.

Comment: I've added an example of using Models to carry this out - do you have an example of the code required to override the edit and delete buttons ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions beforeInsert, afterInsert, beforeDelete, afterDelete and beforeUpdate, afterUpdate to carry out additional processing in the database.  For example
using a unzipped install of ATK 4.1.3 in your webroot creates a folder called agiletoolkit which is referred to below as ATKHOME.

Create a simple table TASKTYPE in mysql with three fields (id, tasktype_desc and budget_code) and another table TASKTYPE_BUDGET with just id and budget_code.

Create two models for the tables in ATKHOME/lib/Model as follows (you may need to create the Model directory if it doesnt exist)

```
class Model_TaskType extends Model_Table {
     public $entity_code='tasktype';
     public $table_alias='ty';

     function defineFields(){
           parent::defineFields();

           $this->newField('id')
               ->mandatory(true);;

           $this->newField('tasktype_desc')
                ->mandatory(true);

           $this->newField('budget_code')
                ->mandatory(true);
      }

      public function afterInsert($new_id){
        $ttb=$this->add('Model_TaskTypeBudget');
        $ttb->set('id',$new_id)
            ->set('budget_code',$this->get('budget_code'));
        $ttb->insert();
        return $this;
      }

      public function beforeUpdate(&$data){
        $ttb=$this->add('Model_TaskTypeBudget')->loadData($data['id']);
        $ttb->set('budget_code', $data['budget_code']);
        $ttb->update();
        return $this;
      }

      public function beforeDelete(&$data){
        $ttb=$this->add('Model_TaskTypeBudget')->loadData($data['id']);
        $ttb->delete();
        return $this;
      }
}
```

Note if you are using innoDB and have foreign keys, you have to do the insert and delete in the right order e.g. if there was a foreign key from TaskTypeBudget to TaskType on ID, then it should use beforeDelete and afterInsert to prevent constraint violations.

```
class Model_TaskTypeBudget extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='tasktype_budget';
    public $table_alias='tyb';

    function defineFields(){
            parent::defineFields();

            $this->newField('id')
                ->mandatory(true);

            $this->newField('budget_code')
                    ->mandatory(true);

    }
}
```

And a page in ATKHOME/page like this

```
class page_tasktype extends Page {

    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $p=$this;

        $tt=$this->add('Model_TaskType');
        $crud=$p->add('CRUD');
        $crud->setModel($tt, array('id','tasktype_desc', 'budget_code'));

        if($crud->grid)
          $crud->grid->addPaginator(10);
        }
}
```

Note also be careful to include an opening < ? php tag before each class line but DO NOT include a closing ? > as this may cause errors in the Ajax.

In ATKHOME/config-default.php, modify the mysql connection username and password from root/root to the user and password of your mysql database.

```
$config['dsn']='mysql://atktest:atktest@localhost/atktest';
```

and modify ATKHOME/lib/Frontend.php to uncomment line 8 which allows all pages to connect to the database (you can also just add the $this->dbConnect(); line to the page.

```
class Frontend extends ApiFrontend {
function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->dbConnect();  //uncommented
```

In the same Frontend.php, insert the following around line 50 to add a button to the default menu to add our new page.

```
->addMenuItem('CRUD Test', 'tasktype')
```

Now go to your webbrowser and enter http://localhost/agiletoolkit and on the first page, click CRUD Test.  Adding rows will result in a row being added to TASKTYPE and a row with the same id and budget_code to TASKTYPE_BUDGET. Editing the budget_code will be reflected in both tables and deleting the row will delete it from both tables.

How neat and simple is that once you know the functions are provided by ATk4 ?