# Agile Toolkit CRUD works perfectly on localhost throws error on server

Tags: php, frameworks, atk4

I need help in ATK4 CRUD. I have built a backend for a project using Agile Toolkit 4.1.3.
I have the following Model:

```
class Model_Product extends Model_Table
{
public $entity_code = 'product';

function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $this->addField('category_id')->refModel('Model_Category')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('name')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('picture_id')->refModel('Model_Picture')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('short_description')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('description')->type('text')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('uploaded_at')->type('datetime');
    $this->addField('price')->type('int')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('quantity')->type('int')->mandatory(true);
    $this->addField('status')->datatype('list')
            ->listData(array(
                        'enabled'=>'Enabled',
                        'disabled'=>'Disabled',
                        ))
            ->defaultValue('enabled');
}
}
```

the page:

```
<?php
class page_index extends Page {
function init(){
    parent::init();
    $page=$this;

    $tabs = $page->add('Tabs');
    $tabs->addTab('Product')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Product');
....
```

On my localhost all CRUD functions work flawlessly, but after I uploaded the files to the webserver when I try to add a new product I get this error:

`Error in AJAX response: SyntaxError: invalid XML attribute value
SQLException

Could not execute query: insert into product (`category_id`, `name`, `picture_id`, `short_description`, `description`, `uploaded_at`, `price`, `quantity`, `status`) values (NULL, 'as', NULL, '', '', NULL, 2500, 25, 'enabled')
Last query:
insert into product (`category_id`, `name`, `picture_id`, `short_description`, `description`, `uploaded_at`, `price`, `quantity`, `status`) values (NULL, 'as', NULL, '', '', NULL, 2500, 25, 'enabled')
MySQL error:
Column 'category_id' cannot be null`

Strange thing that the missing values in the query are visible in the crud form but never make it to the query. Additional info: in Model_Picture I use varchar id field instead of autoincrement int but once again everything works fine on localhost.

Thanks!

Comment: I have added a codepad example with your case here: http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/stackcrud , even through the fields are mandatory, agile toolkit permits leaving them with the empty value. I'm puzzled at the problem, are you absolutely sure tables are identical? can delete and create table again?

Comment: I deleted then added the tables again with sqldump, but the error still exist. I even tried the query above with the NULL and missing values changed to meaningful values and it worked.
Adding a category with the Crud page of Model_Category works.
If I cant find the solution I will rewrite the the whole stuff from scratch at the weekkend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had all my crud functions on one page on tabs like this:

```
<?php
class page_index extends Page {
function init(){
    parent::init();
    $page=$this;

    $tabs = $page->add('Tabs');
    $tabs->addTab('Product')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Product');
    $tabs->addTab('Category')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Category');
    $tabs->addTab('Property')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Property');
    $tabs->addTab('Property <> Product')->add('CRUD')->setModel('ProductProperty');
    $tabs->addTab('Payment options')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Payment');
    $tabs->addTab('Shipping options')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Shipping');
    $tabs->addTab('Users')->add('CRUD')->setModel('User');
    $tabs->addTab('Email addresses')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Email');
    $tabs->addTab('News')->add('CRUD')->setModel('News');
    $tabs->addTab('Downloads')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Download');
    $tabs->addTab('Designer Aids')->add('CRUD')->setModel('Aid');

}
}
```

Then I created a new page for every Model and added only one CRUD on each page and it solved the problem, now it works fine both on localhost and the server.

Thank you guys for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Which platform are you developing on and which platform are you deploying to online.  You can see my previous question which had a similar error when developing locally on windows and then moving to a linux host online here -  [ATK4 model not found when moving to online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465856/atk4-model-not-found-when-moving-to-online)

The error in that case was related to case sensitive issues in Linux whereas Windows is more forgiving of case differences so check your initial capitilsaton in your code.

I also recently got some errors from Ajax with CRUD in 4.1.3 when i included a closing `?>` in the class files. agiletoolkit.org recommends you dont use the closing tags as it can introduce invalid characters in the output which breaks some of the functionality so just ensure you are using `<?php` at the top of each file but omit any `?>`  on the last line.

Comment: The host is Linux and my local platform is Windows but 
I double checked all capitalisation and have not find any mistake, also omitted closing php tags, so still can't find what causes this. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I had the same frustration - as your live and dev environments are on different operating systems, i'm sure it will be a case sensitive issue somewhere but these are really hard to track down - i spent more than a week trying to find my one.  If you have a chance to, maybe install something like Oracle Virtual Box and then create a local unix install and run it from there - it gives you more control over the environment and you can run firebug on firefox in linux which might give you better error reporting than your online host. Cant see anything wrong it what you have posted here.

Answer (score 0):

i am also puzzled as to how a mandatory field:

`$this->addField('description')->type('text')->mandatory(true);`

end up being passed as a **NULL** value in your SQL insert string:

`(NULL, 'as', NULL, '', '', NULL, 2500, 25, 'enabled')`

ATK4 should already give a notification that this field is required and would never lead to an `update()` attempt if the required fields are still empty.

do you have by any chance, a `beforeInsert()` or `beforeModify()` method defined that somehow manipulates this data prior to inserting?

as for the `NULL` value for `category_id`, when adding a new entry, by default, no items are selected for both:

`$this->addField('category_id')->refModel('Model_Category')->mandatory(true);`

and

`$this->addField('picture_id')->refModel('Model_Picture')->mandatory(true);`

so when adding a new entry, the user has to explicitly select from the list first.

for me, if all else fails, i rely on the beforeModify() method and throw a js()->fieldError notification:

try inserting this in your model:

```php
function beforeModify(&$data){
   if(empty($data['category_id'])){
      $this->owner->owner->js()->atk4_form('fieldError','category_id',
         'Select an category from the list')->execute();
      exit;
   }
}
```

please note that you may have to experiment on the `$this->owner->owner` to arrive at the MVCForm object.

also, the `exit()` call is important to prevent the internal `render()` method from producing the HTML page and only produce the Javascript Chain.

I hope this helps.