# Chain a js action on form displayFieldError

Tags: php, forms, atk4

I have a form that use `displayFieldError` when submitted to display errors on fields. I need to show/hide a container on certain error conditions, is possible to chain a js action on it?

Comment: What kind of container? Try calling `$this->downCall('loadPOST'); $this->downCall('validate');`. Then you can mess with `$form->errors`. You can also re-define submit() completely with a copy of Form_Basic::submit, then tweak it the way you like.

Comment: The problem isn't for the container but on the `displayFieldError`.
Internally it executes a thing like this
`$f->js()->atk4_form('fieldError',$field->short_name,$message)->execute();` and is impossible to add other js actions to it without reimplementing all the method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending and redefining methods is a normal practice in Object Oriented development. Besides, you can do that globally by creating this:

```
class Form extends Form_Basic {
    function displayFieldError(){
        .. your actions ..
    }
}
```

This will work across your project and will not loose any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

all Views in Agile Toolkit carries a jquery class and is capable of calling jquery and is also chainable.

**BUT** the object extending the view class **MUST** implement an ID=NAME attribute in its HTML template.

here's an example of a view, a Text object which will not get hidden:

```
 $t=$this->add('Text')->set('Press Buton To Hide Me');
 $b=$this->add('Button');
 $b->js('click',
    $t->js()->hide() // hide it
    )->univ()->successMessage('Hiding Text..'); // js chained
```

its clear that Text objects has javascript capability but will not work on itself, even attaching a `click` command will NOT work.

here's another example of a view, an extended HtmlElement class which **WILL** get hidden:

```
 $t=$this->add('P')->set('Press Buton To Hide Me');
 $b=$this->add('Button');
 $b->js('click',
    $t->js()->hide() // hide it
    )->univ()->successMessage('Hiding Text..'); // js chained
```

inspect both sources and you will immediately see the difference.

therefore, make sure that the *container* you are referring to is a class extension of the View class and its associated Template has an `id="<?$_name?>"` implementation in it.

i am not sure of any other simpler way.

Comment: also, you may want to check my answer here:
[SO-ATK4-Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704789/agile-toolkit-crud-works-perfectly-on-localhost-throws-error-on-server/8767117#8767117)
taking note of the `beforeModify()` function which implements a js() version of the `fieldError`
and appropriately chain additonal js calls to it.

Comment: I'm not having a problem with the container (it has id) but I was asking if there is a way to add js to error handling without reimplement completely `displayFieldError` method.